# When to use "en" vs. "dans"?

Tags: choix-de-mot, prépositions, indications-de-temps, indications-de-lieu

When is it more appropriate to use “en” vs. “dans” when you want to say “in” in French?

Examples:

> I am in the car.
>
> I am in America.
>
> I am in the living room.
>
> The toys are in the box.
>
> The package will arrive in two days.
>
> I can read the book in two hours.
>
> I'm leaving in ten minutes.
>
> He's in the house.

How do you know which preposition to use?  Is there a generic rule to apply?

Comment: You need to ask about specific examples; this question is too vague as it is.

Comment: @Brennan is there no generic rule?  I can come up with examples all day but I need to be able to apply some sort of rule to them, no?

Comment: @Brennan updated with examples. The reason why I ask is because in other languages (Spanish, for example), there are not multiple words to stand for "in" and I find this confusing.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Prepositions are some of the hardest words to put in one-to-one correspondence between two languages. Prepositions usually don't correspond exactly to some logically consistent notion, and "in", "dans", and "en" are no exceptions. For example, in English we say "in a house" and "on a train", where "in" and "on" mean exactly the same thing in these two phrases. I advise you to get used to specific examples of usage, not to try to learn some general rule that will explain everything.

Comment: And be happy you're not dealing with hungarian...

Comment: @Brennan: well put. George Carlin mentioned in one routine (about airlines and English) he wasn't going to get *on* the plane, he was going to get *in* the plane... Nice.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This mostly depends on the size of the place you're referring to. In fact, you could also add "à" in your question.

Here are some general rules.

**En: for large places with a feminine name**

In general, we use "en" for large places, like countries or regions, when they are singular and feminine names or begin with a vowel. That is in fact, countries or regions for which you would use "la" or "l'" to refer to them:

> Countries: En France, en Allemagne, en Italie, en Grande-Bretagne, en Iran (masculine name, but begins with a vowel)
>
> Regions: En Auvergne, en Île-de-France, en Picardie, en Californie, en Corse

**Au/aux: for large places with a masculine or plural name**

For other country names, we use "au" or "aux" (for plural). That is in fact, countries or regions for which you would use "le" or "les" to refer to them:

> Countries: Aux USA, au Canada, au Japon, au Bénin
>
> Regions: Au Kamchatka, au Connemara

**À: for local places**

For localized places, like cities, towns or villages (and sometimes small countries), we use "à":

> Cities: À Paris, à Lyon, à Bordeaux
>
> Small countries: À Monaco, à Taïwan, à Cuba

Note that Andorra is not bigger than Cuba, but we say "En Andorre".

**Dans: for very localized places**

For very localized places, like a house or a box, we use "dans":

> Dans ma maison, dans cette boîte, dans le jardin

**Exceptions to the rules**

There are however exceptions (otherwise it wouldn't be fun):

> Regions: Dans le Berry, dans le Limousin
>
> Cities: En Avignon
>
> Generic places: Dans le ciel, dans la mer

**Expressing time**

To express a lapse of time to wait for, we always use "dans":

> Je pars au Canada dans 3 jours, dans 1 mois, dans un siècle

To express a lapse of time necessary to achieve an action, we use "en":

> Le tour du monde en 80 jours

Comment: For places, countries,... we use it when it's feminime AND when it begins with a consonant.

Comment: Another general category is small countries: A Monaco; à Cuba; à Taïwan.

As for U.S. states, I've heard "Dans l'Arizona" and "En Arizona" with about equal frequency.

Comment: @Louhike: do you have examples of these?

Comment: @Vincent: Thanks, I'll update with this.

Comment: @Brennan Vincent: En Allemagne, en Iran, en Inde, en Angleterre, en Australie, en Autriche,... I don't know a country which begins with a consonant we don't use with "en". It's also explained here (in french): http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/en

Comment: Remember also that "En 3 jours" is also French, but means something different. For example: "Ils ont construit une maison en seulement 3 jours".

Comment: @Louhike: All these examples are feminine names that I can tell. I can't think of a country name beginnning with a vowel that is not feminine in French...

Comment: @Vincent: good point, I'll mention that, too.

Comment: @Raphink: According to the wesite I give, Iran is is not feminine for example.

Comment: @Louhike, you're right about Iran, I'll update my answer.

Comment: I've just realized I wrote "consonant" in my first and second comments instead of "vowel". Sorry for that.

Comment: @Louhike: I noticed, no problem :-)

Comment: Belle réponse! Ça m'a aidé beaucoup. Je souhaite qu'on puisse sauvegarder les réponses.

Comment: @BrennanVincent: "dans l'Arizona profond j'ai trouvé…" vs "je pars en Arizona"

Comment: Interessant. Où placerais-tu "Je vais en ville"?

Comment: These are some good rules of thumb genearlly. You may want to think about: set expressions where 'en' emphasises the 'utility' of an action whereas 'dans' emphasises the 'physical location/movement' (e.g. "mettre dans la soute" vs "mettre en soute"); also cases where 'en' is effectively forced to become 'dans' due to an article being inserted (e.g. "en français" vs "dans un français soigné"); in reality, the situation with regions, notably French departments, is also much more complex than you make out!

Comment: Re the countries, "en" is generally used with feminine singular countries and with masculine (singular) countries beginning with a vowel: so "en Irak", "en Iran", "en Afghanistan" etc. There are a handful of cases of variation (e.g. both "à Haïti" and "en Haïti" are used, though I think the latter is more common nowadays).

Answer (score 4):

In general "en" is used for abstract ideas while "dans" is used for physical locations.

Comment: Surtout en France ? Bienvenue sur le site, *though* :·)

Answer (score 3):

When replacing *in*, the situations where you have to use *en* instead of *dans* are the following:

- When depicting a situation, without articles

  > My son is in sixth grade
  >    Mon fils est en sixième
- For some locutions

  > In front of...
  >    En face de...
- For feminine continents, countries and regions names (all continents are feminine, and almost all countries are feminine, PLUS some masculine country name are also used with *en*)

  > I'm going to Germany
  >    Je vais en allemagne

Exception: Quebec (masculine). note the use of *au* instead of *dans* used for large places like countries / regions

> I'm going to Quebec
>       Je vais au Québec

- For season names

  > I go to the pool in summer
  >   Je vais à la piscine en été
- And some other very special cases

  > In return
  >   En contrepartie / En retour

Note that this list only covers the cases where *en* is used when translating from *in*. You'll find other uses of *en* in other occasions.

Answer (score 1):

In situations where “en” and “dans” are usually translated by “in” a useful guide is to note that “en” is used immediately before a noun, whereas “dans” is followed by an article. Compare

> aller en ville
>
> aller dans la ville

But as with all such guides beware:

> en l'absence de (in the absence of)

Here are a few useful expressions that use “en” which would most likely be translated by “in”.

> être en danger (to be in danger)
>
> être en train de (to be in the process of)
>
> croire en Dieu (to believe in God)
>
> être en bonne santé (to be in good health)
>
> être en difficulté (to be in difficulty)

Comment: A la personne qui a voté contre cette réponse, il aurait été gentil de préciser pourquoi.

Comment: I'm not that one, but if I had to give a shot at criticism, I'd say it doesn't look very complete *at all* to me, merely many special cases, not likely to help simplify matters in the OP's head.