# "En" vs "Dans": proper noun of country vs generic word "country"

Tags: prépositions

Similar to my other [question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/21/when-to-use-en-vs-dans), but I have a very specific example.

> I am in France

vs

> I am in the country (or I am in that country).

Would these translations be correct?

> Je suis en France

and

> Je suis dans le pays (Je suis dans ce pays)

In other words, do  you use

> en (or au/aux if masc)

For a proper noun of a country (France)

and do you use

> dans

for just the general noun "country?"

What is the correct preposition for saying "*in* the country"?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @m42 Is my translation correct?  Do you use en for France and dans for le pays?

Comment: @m42 updated question to clarify better

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your assertion is correct, one must say:

> Je suis dans le (ce) pays.

For a particuliar country:

> Je suis en France, en Angleterre, en Allemagne.
>
> Je suis au Vénézuela, au Japon, aux Seychelles.

But there're some exceptions (as usual in french):

> Je suis à Madagascar, à la Réunion.

Comment: It's always *en* for a country that is singular and either is feminine or begins with a vowel, and *au* or *aux* for a plural. However, when a country is also an island or a town, we refer to the island or town instead of the country. Towns take *à*, islands take either *à* or *en/au* or *sur le/la/les* (with partly size-based and partly ad hoc rules).

Comment: Je ne comprends pas la réponse. Quand utilise-t-on `en` et quand `à`/`au`/`aux`?

Comment: @M42 à toi. Et je ne comprends pas non plus pourquoi "à la Réunion" fait exception "au Japon"...

Comment: @rds: `à la Réunion` fait exception parce que c'est féminin (et de plus c'est une île) alors que ce devrait être `en Réunion`. Exception de l'exception, on dit `en Martinique` bien que ce soit féminin en plus d'être une île. Quant au Japon, bien que masculin, c'est une île...