# « À », « en », « à la », « au(x) » : quel déterminant utiliser pour un pays, une province, ou une ville ?

Tags: prépositions, déterminants, toponymes

La question ["En" vs "Dans": proper noun of country vs generic word "country"](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1799/en-vs-dans-proper-noun-of-country-vs-generic-word-country) répond partiellement à cette question, mais je désirais la pousser plus loin. En effet, elle ne répond que pour les pays.

---

Quand devons-nous utiliser *À*, *en*, *à la* ou *au(x)* comme déterminant devant un pays, une province ou une ville?

Exemples:

- Au Canada (pays)
- Au Québec (province)
- À Québec (ville)
- En Ontario (province)
- À Toronto (Ville)
- Aux États-Unis (Pays)
- En France (Pays)

Etc, la liste est longue.

Questions plus précise : Est-ce toujours *À* devant une ville? Y-a-t-il une règle générale des déterminants concernant les provinces ou est-ce la même chose que pour les pays?

Comment: Je n'ai pas la réponse complète, mais juste pour au, aux: cela remplace à le , à les. Par exemple on dirait Québec est une ville mais Le Québec est un pays, Les États-Unis  sont un pays etc. On ne  pourrait pas  dire Au Paris, Au Toronto pour cette raison.

Comment: @P.Obertelli, mais on peut dire À Paris et À Toronto, le premier un pays et le second une ville. (Québec est une province, pas un pays :))

Comment: Oui, j'explique juste  pourquoi on ne dit pas Au Québec pour la ville: parce que Au remplace "à le " et qu'on ne fait pas précéder un nom de ville de l'article "le, la" sauf si cet article fait partie du nom (La Paz, Les Esclins etc.) Paris n'est pas un Pays et Toronto non plus.

Comment: @P.Obertelli, bien vu! J'ai écris Paris en pensant à France et je ne peux plus éditer mon commentaire, oops.

Comment: Je n'ai pas écrit de réponse, juste un commentaire, parce que moi non plus je ne sais pas pourquoi on dit  Au Québec vs En Ontario...

Comment: Voir aussi [Différentes prépositions pour les noms des départements](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/14044)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Villes**

Si le nom commence explicitement par ***Le***, ***au*** est utilisé :

> **Le** Havre → **Au** Havre
>
> **Le** Mans → **Au** Mans
>
> **Le** Cap → **Au** Cap

S'il commence par ***Les*** ou est manifestement au pluriel avec un *les* sous entendu, ***aux*** est utilisé :

> **Les** Sables-d'Olonne → **Aux** Sables-d'Olonne
>
> Saintes-Maries-de-la-mer → **Aux** Saintes-Maries-de-la-mer

mais *à Saintes, à Los Angeles, à Trois-Rivières, à Six-Fours-les-Plages*

Dans tous les autres cas, les plus nombreux, le nom de la ville est utilisé sans article et on utilise ***à*** :

> Paris → **À** Paris
>
> Québec → **À** Québec
>
> Bruxelles → **À** Bruxelles

Deux exceptions très optionnelles qui survivent essentiellement grâce à des journalistes parisiens<sup>1</sup>, *En Avignon* et *En Arles*, mais *à Amsterdam, à Amiens...*

**Pays**

Si on nomme le pays avec l'article ***l'*** ou ***la***, on utilisera ***en***

> **L**'Allemagne → **En** Allemagne
>
> **La** Belgique → **En** Belgique

Si c'est avec ***le***, on utilisera ***au***

> **Le** Canada → **Au** Canada
>
> **Le** Yémen → **Au** Yémen

Si c'est avec ***les***, ce sera ***aux***

> **Les** États-Unis → **Aux** États-Unis
>
> **Les** Pays-Bas → **Aux** Pays-Bas

Enfin, si le nom n'est jamais utilisé avec un article quand on désigne le pays (essentiellement certaines îles, mais pas que), on utilisera ***à***.

> Cuba → **À** Cuba
>
> Madagascar → **À** Madagascar
>
> Monaco → **À** Monaco

Les zones géographiques suivent les mêmes règles que les pays:

> **Le** Sahara → **Au** Sahara
>
> **L**'Asie → **En** Asie
>
> **Les** Antilles → **Aux** Antilles

Parfois, ***dans les*** est utilisé :

> **Les** Alpes → **Dans les** Alpes (<s>Aux Alpes</s>)

**Régions**

***En*** est la règle sauf pour les régions pour lesquelles un article n'est jamais employé (ici aussi essentiellement des îles) ou si l'article ***La*** est inclus dans le nom, dans ces deux cas on utilise ***à***:

> **En** Berry<sup>2</sup>, **En** Roussillon, **En** PACA, **En** Wallonie, **En** Limousin
>
> **À** Tahiti, **À** La Réunion

Les provinces qui sont aussi des états, ou considérés comme tels, sont nommés comme des pays:

> **Le** Québec → **Au** Québec
>
> **Le** Texas → **Au** Texas
>
> **L**'Ontario → **En** Ontario<sup>2</sup>
>
> **Le** Yucatán → **Au** Yucatán
>
> **La** Louisiane → **En** Louisiane

---

Pour illustrer ces différences, Luxembourg est à la fois le nom d'une ville, d'un pays et d'une région :

> **À** Luxembourg = la ville
>
> **Au** Luxembourg = le pays
>
> **En** Luxembourg = la région belge

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Frédéric Mistral écrivait en provençal, *en Arles, en Avignoun* et même *en Albi* mais aujourd'hui à Arles et à Avignon, ces formes ne sont plus vraiment utilisées.</sub>

<sup>2</sup> <sub>Dans certains cas, ***dans le*** est aussi possible, et parfois plus courant : *je vais **dans le** Berry*, *Il habite **dans l**'Ontario*,etc. Voir la [BDL: Préposition devant les noms d'États américains](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4891)</sub>

Comment: ne dit-on pas "Les Saintes-Marie-de-la-mer" ?

Comment: @radouxju Ça se dit souvent mais le nom officiel de la commune n'a pas d'article.

Comment: Je n'ai évidemment rien à reprocher à cette réponse riche et précise, à laquelle je voudrais cependant apporter un tout petit complément. En ce qui concerne les provinces (du moins françaises, je ne sais pas pour le Canada, les Etats-Unis ou la Belgique), on emploie aussi couramment **dans le**, mais avec deux restrictions : 1) pour les provinces "historiques" seules (d'ailleurs, pour les régions administratives, même le **en** n'est guère utilisé, on dira plutôt _dans la région_ PACA) ; 2) uniquement pour les noms masculins (_dans le_ Berry, _dans le_ Limousin ; _en_ Bretagne, _en_ Alsace).

Comment: @cFreed Ok pour l'utilisation de «dans le» pour certaines régions/provinces mais «en PACA» est beaucoup plus courant que «dans la région PACA», environ cinq fois plus d'après google ngram, aussi «en Rhône-Alpes» comparé à «dans la région Rhône-Alpes».

Comment: Ah tiens, voilà qui est remarquable, et mea culpa ! Je dois préciser que j'ai apporté ce commentaire sur la base informelle de "ce que je crois savoir", du simple fait de mon vécu (dans ce cas précis, l'oral plutôt que l'écrit). Et je prends concscience, en même temps que j'en parle, de la fragilité de la chose : quel que soit ce vécu, il ne saurait avoir valeur universelle, ce qui amène la question de la pertinence des réponses ici, dès qu'elles ne sont pas exclusivement fondées sur la référence à de véritables travaux. Par ailleurs, merci : j'ignorais l'existence de Google ngram !

Comment: Excellent answer, very complete and with good examples ! Anyway, I wouldn't want to be the guy who asked it and who will have to learn all that by heart :( Certains trucs évidents pour les français deviennent des vacheries quand il faut les apprendre ;)

Comment: Pour certains états américains, l'usage principal au Québec est "dans le", comme "Dans le Maine", plutôt "qu'au Maine". Est-ce spécifique au Québec? http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4891

Comment: @Jeffrey Pas forcément spécifique, *dans le Maine*, jamais *en Maine* ou *au Maine* (mais ici: *en Maine-et-Loire*).  Je dirais aussi plus *dans le New-Jersey* mais *au Nouveau-Mexique* et jamais *dans le Texas* (sauf *dans le Texas profond*). *Dans le Mississipi* me donne l'impression d'être tombé à l'eau...

Answer (score 2):

Pour autant que je le sache, on met toujours **À** devant un nom de ville.

Pour ce qui est des pays, on utilise toujours **En** sauf pour les pays "au pluriel" (États-Unis, Émirats Arabes Unis ...), les pays masculins qui commencent par une consonne (Canada, Brésil ...) pour lesquels on utilise **Au**,  sauf les *"petites"* îles (Chypre, Malte ...) pour lesquelles on utile **À**. À noter qu'on utilise également **À** pour Madagascar qui n'est pas une petite île !
On dit **Au** Sri Lanka mais **À** Ceylan, on distingue l'île du pays.

Pour les provinces, *a priori*, on utilise la même règle que pour les pays.
en faisant un *distingo* entre les *anciennes provinces* et les régions administrative, tout au moins en France.

Comment: @Sifu: J'ai modifié ma réponse en même temps :-)

Comment: Merci beaucoup à la personne qui a donné un point négatif sans explication.

Comment: c'est systématiquement incorrect. Dès qu'une ville possède un article (l'origine est une autre question), il faut en tenir compte, par une contraction avec un nom masculin. à  Le Mans => au Mans. à Le Touquet => au Touquet. Idem pour les pays, ... La réponse de @jlliagre paraît exhaustive et explique tout ça.

Answer (score -1):

Concernant les villes, c'est effectivement toujours "à" sauf quand il faut éviter un hiatus: "en Avignon", "en Arles", bien que le "à" soit souvent utilisé à l'oral.

Comment: Hmm, en Amiens ?

Comment: @jlliagre Le provençal rejetait plus les hiatus que l'oïl (voir [Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avignon#.C2.AB_.C3.80_Avignon_.C2.BB_ou_.C2.AB_en_Avignon_.C2.BB_.3F)). Mais « en Arles » et « en Avignon » doivent surtout leur popularité parce que la formulation était utilisée pour désigner le royaume d'Arles (pas la ville) et l'état pontifical d'Avignon (pas la ville) qui n'existent plus depuis des siècles.

Comment: [Ils sont redevenus à la mode au XXe siècle](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=en+Arles%2F%C3%A0+Arles%2C+en+Avignon%2F%C3%A0+Avignon%2Cen+Aubagne%2F%C3%A0+Aubagne%2Cen+Aix%2F%C3%A0+Aix&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28en%20Arles%20/%20%C3%A0%20Arles%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28en%20Avignon%20/%20%C3%A0%20Avignon%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28en%20Aubagne%20/%20%C3%A0%20Aubagne%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28en%20Aix%20/%20%C3%A0%20Aix%29%3B%2Cc0), probablement par hypercorrection.

Comment: On trouve quand même « [en Aix](https://books.google.fr/books?id=W0AbAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA312&dq=%22en+aix%22) » par exemple, mais c'est très rare. En tout cas présenter *à* comme non-standard pour Arles et Avignon est faux.

Comment: @Gilles, Oui, *à Arles* est la formulation standard. Il y a encore quelques personnes parlant le provençal autour d'Aix et elle disent *a-z-Aïs* pour *à Aix*. *En Aix* / *A-n-Aïs* ne s'est jamais dit en provençal.

Comment: Merci pour vos précisions et corrections. Effectivement je n'avais pas pensé à Amiens ;-)

Comment: "en" provient plus de pratiques régionales (provençales), qui souvent parlent de "pays" pour des zones géographiques. En général, on entend toujours à Aix, à Arles, à Istanbul ...