# "Au(x)" et "en", pour qualifier ce qui concerne un pays ou une région

Tags: usage

Je ne parviens pas à déterminer s'il existe une règle régissant l'emploi de "au(x)" et "en" pour qualifier ce qui concerne un pays ou une région.

Par exemple, on dit:

> En France, les élections présidentielles auront lieu en mai.

Tandis que l'on dit:

> Aux Etats-Unis, elles auront lieu en novembre.

J'ai d'abord pensé que c'est l'emploi du mot "Etats" ou "Pays" qui conditionne cela, mais ce n'est pas si simple:

"En"

- Allemagne
- Autriche
- France
- Roumanie
- Bohème
- Poitou-Charentes
- Angleterre
- République Dominicaine
- République Démocratique du Congo
- ...

"Au(x)":

- Royaume-Uni
- Etats-Unis
- Etats-Unis du Mexique
- Pays Bas
- ...

Certes, mais aussi "au(x)":

- Canada
- Guatemala
- Mexique
- Swaziland
- Groenland
- ...

Dans ces deux derniers cas, "land" pourrait expliquer l'emploi de "au", d'autant que l'on dirait "en Swazilandie", "en Groenlie", si ces pays s'appelaient ainsi. Mais quid du Canada, du Guatemala, ou encore du Mexique ?

Visiblement, Il n'y a pas non plus de lien avec le genre et le nombre (emploi de "du, "des" et "de la") puisque Poitou-Charentes, dans les exemples ci-dessus, sert justement de contre-exemple.

Alors, y a-t-il une règle autre que l'usage ?

Comment: Plusieurs réponses à ce sujet ont déjà été données [ici](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/16974/7321), et je pense qu'il y à la même réflexion pour les régions / villes, et jlliagre propose une raison de genre (masculin / féminin)

Comment: Oh, merci @Random ! J'ai donc mal cherché ! Je ferme la question pour cause de doublon.

Comment: j'ai cherché "pays en" :) Après, une réflexion en découle: comment connaît-on le genre d'un pays (si ce n'est cas par cas...)

Comment: @Random Et moi "en aux qualifier pays", pourquoi faire simple ? :) Quant au genre, j'imagine sans certitude qu'il est choisi par le pays, comme sa dénomination officielle ?