# Must I use “la”, “le”, “l'” etc. in front of country or city names?

Tags: articles, indications-de-lieu, noms-propres

When I use Google translate, I get: `China -> Chine` etc. However according to this [French Country Names](http://www.frenchlearner.com/vocabulary/countries/), `la, le, l'` etc are in front of country names.
Is Google wrong?

If I write `Distance de Australie à Chine` instead of `Distance de l'Australie à la Chine`, will this be considered very bad French?

In what situations I can write `Chine` instead of `la Chine`?

How about city names? Do I need  la, le, l' etc in front of city names?

Comment: Liés: [Règle général pour les endroits](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/16974/%C3%80-en-%C3%A0-la-aux-quel-d%C3%A9terminant-utiliser-pour-un-pays-une?noredirect=1&lq=1)  and [son post précédant](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/21738/many-forms-of-to-au-aux-en-%C3%A0-l-%C3%A0-etc-which-one-to-use)

Comment: As we told you in our previous comments, you **must** definitely use the definite article in French in front of country names in the sentence of the type  *Distance de l'Australie à la Chine*. You would use the definite article after the word *en*, but you don't want it for what you want to say.  We'd use *en* in *Je vais en France* (I'm going to France).  With city names you would not use the definite article except if the name is plural. If you do not understand the answer on that matter we pointed to you earlier, we will translate it but there's no need to write another answer.

Comment: This question was unnecessary after [your previous one](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/21738/many-forms-of-to-au-aux-en-%C3%A0-l-%C3%A0-etc-which-one-to-use) at best you could edit it if you want more information on the same topic.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In French country names have gender, so we say `la France` as France is considered feminine or `le portugal` as Portugal is considered masculine.

some country whose name begin with vowel `Espagne Italie Allemagne Australie` still have gender but are written with `l'` so we say `l'Espagne`.

Most of the countries have gender, but of course there is exceptions. for instance we say `Cuba` or `Israel` which don't have any `le la l'`

Comment: Not to be picky or anything but do you have any sources with numbers to back your _Most of the countries have feminine gender_ statement? It's just for my personnal knowledge so don't feel obligated.

Comment: Welcome to French Language dominix.  Please visit [the Help Centre](http://french.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) to see how to write good answers. You are not really answering OP's question here. And what you are saying has [already been answered](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/16986/358). Hope to see you again soon.

Comment: yes : https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_des_pays_du_monde

Comment: @Laure Well I wrote my comment before he had edited his answer. So at that point I just wanted numbers like 268 feminine country 54 masculine (which i know won't help the OP).

Comment: @Robijoe "Most of" doesn't mean anyhing and would never help OP, we must go by [**rules** if there any and  learn the exceptions](http://francisationmaryse.blogspot.fr/2012/03/des-pays-feminins-ou-masculins.html). So countyr names ending with *ie* are feminine except a few.   And of course let's not forget countries that are plural, which  are neither masculine nor feminine.

Comment: remove `feminine`