# When to use “à la” vs “à” vs “en”?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, articles, indications-de-lieu

I don't understand the use of the French preposition *à* with articles. Sometimes the article and the preposition stay separate, as in *Elle reste à la maison*, and sometimes they merge, as in *Je vais en France*. In other cases, the article is altogether absent, as in *Je suis à bout de souffle* and *à court terme*. Could someone logically explain to me how I can differentiate between these cases.

Comment: There are several difficulties here. One of them is the choice of the preposition before locations: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/16974, https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/21738

Answer (score 2):

We use the contracted articles [à la/ au/ aux/ du/ de la/ des etc.] with all nouns except countries. For expressing "to the/ at the" with countries only, [en/ à/ aux/ au] are used. So in your example, la maison sees the use of "à la" whereas France(being a country) is preceeded by "en".

Answer (score 1):

There is no merging process involved; if you mean by merging something as in "à le => au", that is called rather "contraction" and that has nothing to do with whether to use "à la" or "en"; "à" is one preposition used among other things to indicate the place **where** something is and also the place where someone/something goes and also to give indications of time. "En" is another preposition, and that one is used to indicate basically a place **where** someone/something is or **into which** someone/something goes and also to give indications of time. The meaning of this one is comparable to that of "dans".

**A/** **à la, à l'**

- For nouns that are **not** the nouns of countries or regions which gender is feminine (Amérique, Allemagne, Belgique,…) one of the two forms is used according as the noun begins with a consonant or not; if the consonant is an h, then you use "à l'" when the h is a so called "h muet".

  > Elle est à la gare. _ Les enfants vont à la gare. _ Ces jeunes sont à l'armée. _ Les jeunes vont à l'armée à dix-huit ans. _ Il a été blessé à la hanche. _ Je te le dirait à la saison des fleurs.
- ready made phrases without the article (no indication of location)

  > **À (la) seule fin de** (*the speaker can choose whether to use the article or not*)
  >   Les gens avaient couru **à perte de souffle**. _ Mettez du grain dans le second plateau de la balance jusqu'**à concurrence de** trente grammes.

**B/** **en**

- For the nouns that are the names of countries and regions "en" must be used; that is nothing else but a matter of usage; however there are exceptions.

  > la France => en France, l'Espagne => en Espagne; Camargue => en Camargue, Île-de- France => en Île-de-France
  >
  > à la Martinique, à la Guadeloupe,
- For common nouns there two possibilities to distinguish among others;

  - normal usage with the article; indication of place, and of time but for certain nouns on.

    > En la (*ou* sa) partie supérieure la boite comprend des trous. _ L'explosion la détruisit en son entièreté. 
    >   C'est arrivé en l'année 1959. _ Il les reverrait en la saison du renouveau.
  - ready made phrases without the article (indication of location or otherwise)

    > des sardines en boite _ Il y avait sur la table des livres en pile. _ La confiture est mise en pot toute chaude.