# Article for king, capital, etc. of country

Tags: articles, indications-de-lieu, noms-propres

I saw an [article](http://www.lemonde.fr/les-decodeurs/article/2016/10/13/elisabeth-ii-le-regne-le-plus-long_5013246_4355770.html) from *Le Monde* in which the king of Thailand is referred to as *roi de Thaïlande*. This surprised me as I thought cases like this require an article (*roi de la Thaïlande*), like we say [*capitale de la France*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capitale_de_la_France). Why is there a difference here? What is the rule?

I've read other questions on articles with countries such as [this one](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/16974/%C3%80-en-%C3%A0-la-aux-quel-d%C3%A9terminant-utiliser-pour-un-pays-une), but they address different issues than the one in this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a special rule that you can find on [BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3517):

> L'article devant le nom de pays est aussi omis dans quelques autres contextes. Lorsqu'ils sont précédés de **roi** ou de **royaume**, les noms de pays singuliers qui sont féminins ou qui commencent par une voyelle (ainsi que Portugal et Danemark) ne sont pas précédés de l'article. De même, les noms de régions qui suivent un titre de noblesse ou une indication de territoire ne sont souvent pas précédés de l'article eux non plus.

It says that there is no article before a country name when there is king or kingdom before these, only for feminine and starting-with-vowel ones(+ exception : *Portugal* and *Danemark*). <sub>As well as land or state after a nobility title or territory indication which are not preceded by an article.</sub>

Comment: Interesting point about Portugal and Danemark. I suspect that saying "le Roi du Portugal" or "le Roi du Danemark" is a very common mistake for any French speaker.

Comment: Totally agree. The main problem about French even for native is the amount of exceptions. (Don't forget that when you heard about "le Roi du Portugal" or "le Roi du Danemark", it is often from journalists, and they aren't a very reliable source for correct French.)

Comment: So for sentences like "Elle vient du sud de **la** Thaïlande", you do need the "la", right?

Comment: Yes, but you will say "Elle vient du sud du royaume de Thaïlande."

Comment: @Gilles Ça m'a frappé aussi cette parenthèse sur le Portugal et le Danemark ; j'ai vérifié c'est LBU14 à 588c1 : avec roi et royaume et les équivalents (empereur, tsar, shah), quand on utilise la prép. _de_ pour l'origine, il n'y a pas d'article avec les noms singuliers soit fem. soit commençant avec voyelle ET avec deux noms masc. commençant avec consonne et on donne directement Portugal et Danemark. On demande de comparer avec 1051a1 (emplois avec _en_).

Comment: @Faʁdɔʃɔtɔmatabaʁwɛt Oh, I see, I misread. The article claims that you should say “roi de Portugal” and “roi de Danemark”. I dispute that claim. It was true a few centuries ago, but at the time it would have applied to other places (e.g. “roi de Congo”). In modern French, I dispute the idea that “[roi du Portugal](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=roi+du+Portugal%2C+roi+de+Portugal&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Croi%20du%20Portugal%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Croi%20de%20Portugal%3B%2Cc0)” is incorrect.

Comment: @Gilles Je comprends, c'est exactement pourquoi leur propos m'a surpris. Faudrait que je me procure un _LBU_ du jour pour voir si on nuance. Il y a un glissement parce qu'on avait _il en est souvent de même_ ds. le texte au LBU pour parler de l'absence de l'article avec fém/commen. par voyelle, alors qu'avec _roi/royaume_, on dit _manque non seulement_ etc. C'est qu'avec _souvent_ rien ne peut être _incorrect_...

Answer (score 3):

In some cases, the definite article is omitted before the name of a country or region. The exact rules can be difficult to figure out, [even for natives](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7508/je-viens-dallemagne-ou-je-viens-de-lallemagne).

In expressions relating to the government of a country or region, the definite article is usually omitted, if the name starts with a vowel or is feminine.

> Le Royaume de Thaïlande. (La Thaïlande)
>   Le Royaume de Belgique. (La Belgique)
>   La République de Chine. (La Chine)
>   La République d'Allemagne. (L'Allemagne, féminin)
>   Le Royaume d'Afghanistan. (L'Afghanistan, masculin)

With a masculine noun starting with a consonant, the single-word form *du* remains.

> L'Empire du Japon. (Le Japon)
>   Le Royaume du Congo. La République du Congo. (Le Congo)
>   Le Royaume du Danemark. (Le Danemark)

Until some time around the classic age (until the 18th century? I don't know exactly when the cut-off was), masculine forms also used *de* rather than *du*, but depending on the country this either has disappeared or is disappearing. While [some prescriptivists](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3517) hold on to *le Royaume de Danemark* and *le royaume de Portugal* (and I wonder why these two specifically), they are no more warranted than *le royaume de Congo* (decidedly old-fashioned) or *<s>*l'Empire de Japon*</s> (didn't take on until it was too late for *de*).

For some non-monarchic regimes, the adjective is used instead of the noun: *la République française*, *la République espagnole*, *la République italienne*, *la Confédération helvétique*, … But *la République d'Allemagne*, *la République d'Irlande* Maybe the republic has to have existed since the 19th century? I'm not sure about this.

This also applies to heads of state who personify the country, as opposed to heads of state who represent the people.

> Le roi de France
>   Le roi de Belgique
>   Le shah d'Iran
>   L'empereur de Russie
>   L'empereur du Japon
>   Le sultan du Maroc

but *le président français, irlandais, chinois, congolais, …*, or “*le président de la RDC [République Démocratique du Congo]*, *le président de la Corée du Nord*” when the country needs to be named.

There is a nuance between “*le roi de France*” and “*le roi des Français*” (lit. King of France vs. King of the French). The *roi de France* claims his authority from his own might or from God. The *[roi des Français](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roi_des_Fran%C3%A7ais)* claims his authority from a mandate of the people. To say that people revolted over this is only a slight exaggeration — while it wasn't the cause of the revolutions per se, it was a very important symbol.