# Les Trois-Rivières?

Tags: québec, toponymes

Lu de la plume de l’anthropologue Serge Bouchard et publié en 2016 :

> En plus des camions Miron, je m’intéressais aussi à ceux qui passaient devant chez moi, halant leurs remorques sur les chemins du Roy. Ils s’en allaient **aux** Trois-Rivières, vers Shawinigan, à Québec et plus loin encore, peut-être.

On connaît aujourd’hui la [ville **de** Trois-Rivières](http://www.v3r.net/), et on dirait plutôt : *« Ils s’en allaient **à** Trois-Rivières »*.

Dans la foulée de cette singularisation des trois rivières, la *Banque de dépannage linguistique* [ne recommande que le singulier](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=1608) pour parler de Trois-Rivières, et se montre même disposée à approuver le masculin (!) :

- Le représentant de la Ville a dit combien Trois-Rivières était **fière** de cette initiative.
- Trois-Rivières est **situé** à mi-chemin entre Québec et Montréal.

On remarquera aussi que la majorité des entités municipales du Québec qui pourraient faire autrement semblent adopter officiellement le même modèle de désignation que Trois-Rivières :

- Ville **de** Baie-Comeau, **de** Deux-Montagnes, **de** Pont-Rouge, **de** Sept-Îles, **de** Val d’Or
  <sub>(et non ville **de la** Baie-Comeau, **des** Deux-Montagnes, **du** Pont-Rouge, **des** Sept-Îles, **du** Val d’Or<sup>1</sup>)</sub>

L’usage médiatique et populaire suit le bal :

- Je vais **à** Baie-Comeau, **à** Deux-Montagnes, **à** Pont-Rouge, **à** Sept-Îles, **à** Val d’Or
  <sub>(et non **à la** Baie-Comeau, **aux** Deux-Montagnes, **au** Pont-Rouge, **aux** Sept-Îles, **au** Val d’Or)</sub>

Inspiré par la première réponse donnée à cette question, j’ai pu trouver quelques exceptions concernent des entités municipales dont le nom commence par un article défini, mais elles ne concernent cependant pas celles qui commencent par un adjectif numéral *(comme Trois-Rivières, dont il est ici question)* :

- Les Escoumins, à propos **desquels** on peut trouver, sur leur [site officiel](http://www.escoumins.ca/) :
     *Municipalité **des** Escoumins, s’imprégner de la vie **aux** Escoumins, ...*
- Le Bic, similairement :
     *Municipalité **du** Bic, se rendre **au** Bic, ...*

Comme M. Bouchard parle de son enfance dans les années ’50 et ’60, tout porte à croire qu’il s’exprime comme on s’exprimait à cette époque. Je me demande si cet usage à cette époque reflète la version officielle d’alors <sup>2</sup>, un usage populaire montréalais, ou simplement un usage qui était encore flottant et indécis.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Je note toutefois que dans l’usage oral, il est encore courant d’entendre dire *« aller **au** Havre »* ou *« en se dirigeant vers **le** Havre »* en désignant ce qui officiellement est la municipalité **de** Havre-Saint-Pierre.</sub>

<sup>2</sup> <sub>*Norme qui aurait alors été plus conforme aux usages français encore en vigueur aujourd’hui, d’après la première réponse et le premier commentaire ci-dessous.*</sub>

Comment: L'usage en France est d'utiliser le pluriel si le nom de la ville est un pluriel manifeste (ex: Je vais **aux** Saintes-Maries-de-la-Mer). Voir https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/16974/%C3%80-en-%C3%A0-la-aux-quel-d%C3%A9terminant-utiliser-pour-un-pays-une/16986#16986

Comment: @PapaPoule *Le maire **des** Saintes-Maries-de-la-Mer* too, http://www.lessaintesmaries.fr/mairie/le-maire

Comment: @jlliagre Merci pour la référence. Cet usage pour les municipalités et villes du Québec semble cependant restraint à celles, peu nombreuses, qui incluent l’article initial dans leur nom officiel. Quant à celles commençant par Deux ou Trois (Deux-Montagnes, Trois-Rivières), l'usage semble désormais les traiter comme un nom propre où les déterminants numéraux sont vidés de leur sens. Je ne sais pas quand a eu lieu la transition, et si même elle a eu lieu. Ce que je sais, c'est que je n'avais jamais rencontré *«aux Trois-Rivières»* auparavant.

Comment: On trouve des toponymes en France et en Belgique qui ont la même construction et suivent le même usage (France: la commune *de* Deux-Chaises;Belgique: commune *de* Trois-Points). Par contre, on parle bien du département *des* Deux-Sèvres ou du royaume *des* Deux-Siciles. Peut-être parce que le nom ne renvoie pas à un lieu précis tel une ville ou une commune ? Ou parce que le nom "compte" deux noms qui sont eux-mêmes des toponymes et non des noms communs ?

Comment: À titre d'information si ça vous intéresse, on trouve parfois des détails linguistiques ou historiques pertinents ou intéressants ds. la [_Banque de noms de lieux du Québec_](http://www.toponymie.gouv.qc.ca/ct/ToposWeb/recherche.aspx?avancer=oui) de la Commission de toponymie du Québec... Merci !

Answer (score 3):

Une recherche de terrain m’a fourni hier un témoignage qui m’indique que la tournure au pluriel *(aller **aux** Trois-Rivières)* était celle utilisée par les anciens encore dans les années ’70 & ’80  dans la région de Portneuf *(rive gauche du Saint-Laurent, en aval de Trois-Rivières, alors que Montréal se trouve en amont).*

Je n’ai point reçu d’indications du caractère formel ou informel de la chose, mais il en résulte au moins un agrandissement du secteur géographique de l’utilisation du pluriel, et une percée de deux décennies vers le présent.

---

### Mise à jour

Documents d’archives indiquant le pluriel :

- [Manoir Boucher de Niverville, document daté de 1685](http://www.ameriquefrancaise.org/media-7563/7563_manoir_boucher_7.jpg) → Les 3. rivieres
- [Trois-Rivières d’autrefois](http://www.patrimoinequebec.ca/Archive/BIBLIOTHEQUE/M%C3%A9langes%20Historiques-Volume%2018.pdf), un document publié à Montréal en 1931. La première page de texte indique :

  > Le 1er avril 1655, dans l'inventaire des biens de feu Mathieu Labat, le  mot « ville » **des** Trois-Rivières est employé pour la première fois. On vient de le rencontrer en 1668. Je le retrouve en 1676 dans le titre de la seigneurie de Gentilly, accordé à Michel Pelletier par l'intendant Duchesneau et daté de « la ville **des** Trois-Rivières ».
- Il ne semble pas que ce soit l’exception, [cet autre document](http://www.patrimoinequebec.ca/Archive/BIBLIOTHEQUE/Histoire%20de%20la%20Ville%20des%20Trois-Rivi%C3%A8res%20et%20de%20ses%20Environs.pdf), ainsi que quelques autres que j’ai pu consulter, utilisent aussi tout au long le pluriel. Aucun des anciens documents n’indiquait le singulier.

Il semble donc que la tournure mentionnée dans la question soit non seulement légitime, mais encore celle qu’ont le plus longtemps connue les Trois-Rivières.

---

Un [autre document](http://depot-e.uqtr.ca/3579/1/000654593.pdf), mémoire d’une maîtrise en études québécoises sur Dollard Dubé, dont l’auteur semble soucieux de rigueur et utilise à la fois le singulier et le pluriel. Il semble qu’aient cohabités un temps l’un et l’autre pour désigner différentes entités. Nous avons entre autres :

- ...en référence à la ville :
  → *De 1921 à 1925, il était échevin de la ville **des** Trois-Rivières.*
  → *En 1964, la Ville **de** Trois-Rivières reconnaît en effet le mérite de Dollard Dubé comme historien régional.*
- Ailleurs, on mentionne :
  → *Le séminaire **de** Trois-Rivières* (1929)
  → *La Commission scolaire **des** Trois-Rivières* (ca.1932)
  → *Le nouvelliste **de** Trois-Rivières* (nom d’un journal, 1938)

Vraisemblablement, la transition vers l’usage actuel a été graduelle. Peut-être ultimement consommée au moment où la ville devient officiellement la ville **de** Trois-Rivières. Mais en quelle année est-ce survenu ? Voilà néanmoins où j’en suis.

Answer (score 1):

L'usage est encore courant aujourd'hui : **48 chambres d'hôtes aux Eyzies-de-Tayac-Sireuil et ses environs** par exemple.

Comment: Je note que cette commune est en France et que son nom officiel est *«**Les** Eyzies-de-Tayac-Sireuil»*. C’est très intéressant parce qu’il existe bien au moins un lieu au Québec dont le nom commence par l’article **Les**, soit [***Les Escoumins***](http://www.escoumins.ca/), dont le site officiel (titre de l’onglet *«Municipalité **des** Escoumins»*) indique d’entrée de jeu *«Nous vous invitons à vous imprégner de la vie **aux** Escoumins»*. Rien de semblable pour Trois-Rivières, cependant. Merci de votre réponse.

Comment: Est-ce que «et **leurs** environs» serait plus conforme? Ou est-ce la manière habituelle d’y reférer?

Comment: Je ne pense pas, mais sans certitudes .. en tout cas j'aime la logique de cette question ..