# Emploi de « en » ou de « au » pour un lieu

Tags: prépositions, indications-de-lieu

> Vos Cucugnanais ne sont ni au paradis ni au purgatoire, ils sont en enfer.

Citation tirée de *Le curé de Cucugnan* (Alphonse Daudet).

Pourquoi cette différence dans le choix de la prépositon pour « en enfer » ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tout simplement parce que *enfer* commence par une voyelle, mais ont dira *aux enfers* en prononçant aux[ z’]enfers.

---

***Compléments : intégration des commentaires***

1 —  Peut-on remplacer *au* et *en* avec *dans* (plus l’article défini) ?

Pas vraiment :

- *au* indique plutôt un lieu, une adresse, un espace lié à une action (aller *au* marché),
- *en* s’il s’agit d’un état, une situation (être *en* face de …)
- et *dans* est englobant :

> Elle court *dans* ***le*** [action] marché, et s’y est mise *dans* ***un*** *état* pas possible.

2 — … à la suite des autres réponses, *à l’enfer* est un concept, une abstraction, une image, *dans* ne convient pas … sauf si le locuteur y croit et en précise le propriétaire (réification) :

> « Tu finiras dans les enfers du Diable » … même si je préférerais ceux d’Hadès avec leur Champs-Élysées et l’eau du Léthé !

3 — "Hmm! This would appear to have been a gap in my knowledge" :

*À l’* chez les très jeunes enfants, se transforme en *au* quand les règles et usages sont maîtrisés.

Ici,  ce n’est pas un problème de genre, mais d’initiale :

> « Du Paradis à l’Enfer » (d’un lieu à l’autre)

est cohérent, sans majuscules se pose le problème des conventions entre écrit et oral où la différence graphique n’est pas audible, mais  le contexte, la phrase complétée et l’intonation du locuteur peuvent nous faire saisir la spécificité liée à cet Enfer, alors qu’une transcription sans majuscule ne passe pas aux yeux des correcteurs.

3<sup>bis</sup> — … si vous cherchez à maîtriser une langue, et en particulier le français, à travers la seule grammaire (***les règles** d’une langue*) … ***Hmm!** … « vous n’êtes pas sorti des ronces ! ».*

Observez qu’il n’y aucune notion de grammaire dans mes réponses, car la grammaire n’est pas l’outil d’apprentissage des enfants, les seuls qu’ils maîtrisent : apprendre les exemples et en comprendre les
supports objectifs (pas conceptuels) … … … retrouvez vôtre âme d’enfant, jouez avec les mots, inventez des solutions et seulement ensuite tamisez les solutions proposées avec ***la logique** de la langue*, c’est-à-dire avec le bon sens … qui s’affine par une pratique régulière et mène à sa maîtrise.

Comment: Merci. Peut-on remplacer au et en avec dans (plus l'article défini) ?

Comment: @dimitris — Pas vraiment : *au* indique plutôt un lieu, une adresse, un espace lié à une action (aller au marché), *en* s’il s’agit d’un état, une situation (être en face de …) et *dans* est englobant :  elle court *dans* **le** [action]  marché, et s’y est mise *dans* **un** *état* pas possible — *enfer* est un concept, une abstraction, une image, *dans* ne convient pas … sauf si le locuteur y croit et en précise le propriétaire (réification) : « Tu finiras dans les enfers du Diable » (même si je préférerais ceux d’Hadès avec leur Champs-Élysées et l’eau du Léthé).

Comment: Pour corroborer cette réponse, on notera que « à l'enfer » est tout à fait possible, mais on a décidé contre sans doute pour des raisons de style.

Comment: @LukeSawczak *À l'enfer* is not possible here, just like we do not say *je suis à l'Amérique* or *à l'Europe*.

Comment: @jlliagre But my understanding was that that's because those are feminine place names and must be preceded by *en*, unlike masculine ones like *au Mexique*. Whereas *enfer* is masculine. Are you saying *à l'enfer* is possible in other contexts (as Google seems to turn up), and if so can you put your finger on what's wrong here?

Comment: @LukeSawczak *À l'enfer* is possible is some cases, *jusqu'à l'enfer* (in competition with *jusqu'en enfer*), *du paradis à l'enfer*, *survivre/échapper/condamner/croire à l'enfer* but with *être*, *enfer* is like a country name or a region. We do not say *je suis à l'Argentine* but *je suis en Argentine* while we say *je suis au Brésil* and not *je suis en Brésil*. See https://french.stackexchange.com/a/16986/1109

Comment: Je crois que c'est la même chose : au Mexique, au Brésil mais en Iran (tous masculins). Au paradis, en enfer.

Comment: Hmm! This would appear to have been a gap in my knowledge.

Comment: @LukeSawczak — *À l’* chez les très jeunes enfants, se transforme en *au* quand les règles et usages sont maîtrisés, et, ce n’est pas un problème de genre, mais d’initiale. — « Du Paradis à l'Enfer » (d’un lieu à l’autre)  est cohérent, sans majuscules se pose le problème des conventions entre écrit et oral où la différence phonétique n’est pas audible, mais ou le contexte, la phrase complétée et l’intonation du locuteur peuvent nous faire saisir la spécificité liée à cet Enfer, alors qu’une transcription sans majuscule ne passe pas aux yeux des correcteurs.