# « En leur présence » pourquoi la préposition est « en », et pas « à » ou « dans » ?

Tags: prépositions, en

*En leur présence* est une expression courante.

Puisque la distinction décrite dans [When to use "en" vs "dans"?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/21/when-to-use-en-vs-dans) ne paraît pas englober cet usage, je m'en enquiers ici : Pourquoi « en leur présence » et pas **à leur présence** ni **dans leur présence** ?

Comment: Pourquoi pas? En quoi *à leur présence* ou *dans leur présence* seraient plus logiques, plus intuitifs, plus corrects?

Comment: @AlexisPigeon: Les trois tournures m'apparaissaient vraies. SVP, voudriez-vous expliciter en tant qu'une réponse pourquoi les deux ne sont plus logiques ni plus intuitifs ni plus corrects ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*En leur présence* remplace ici *en la présence de ces personnes*, et *en présence de* est une locution fixe (voir [présence, I. C. 2.](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/pr%C3%A9sence)).

Il ne s'agit donc pas d'un complément de lieu; d'ailleurs on ne peut pas dire *en présence* sans préciser de quoi. J'aurais envie de comparer à *en face de*: on ne dit pas non plus *je suis assis dans la face de Pierre*.

Comment: "on ne dit pas non plus *je suis assis dans la face de Pierre*", on pourrait, on pourrait...

Answer (score 3):

```
En leur présence
```

est une locution prépositive, cela signifie donc que c'est une expression qui doit être utilisée "telle quelle" (c'est une sorte d'exception due à l'usage). "Dans" et "en" sont des prépositions de lieux, et sont donc généralement utilisés pour introduire un complément circonstanciel de lieux.