# Preposition to use with plural town name

Tags: indications-de-lieu, noms-propres, contractions

I have a relative in a town called *Les Pieux* in Normandy.

What is the correct preposition to use to say, for example, that I am in this town?

I understand from [this question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/21/when-to-use-en-vs-dans/) that we would use "aux" for plural countries/regions but am unsure of the equivalent for towns.

I have heard suggestions of:

> Je suis à Les Pieux.
>
> Je suis aux Pieux.

Answer (score 4):

It might depend on the actual village. I know only of examples that do change.

- town: Le Mans: je suis au Mans
- town: Les Deux Alpes: je suis aux Deux Alpes
- town: Les Sables-d'Olonne: je suis des Sables d'Olonne (I come from...)
- county: Les Deux Sèvres: je suis en Deux Sèvres

Ultimately, the answer for Les Pieux is that it does change. The proof for that is that the city hall calls itself « Mairie des Pieux » and not « *Mairie de Les Pieux ». You can see that on their [website](http://www.lespieux.fr/) (check the footer).

So the correct answer is: « je suis aux Pieux ».

Answer (score -3):

You should use :

> Je suis à Les Pieux
>   Je suis à Paris etc...

For countries or region it will be « en » je suis en France, je suis en Normandie etc.

Je suis au Pieux : it is a way to say that you are in your bed.

[Here](http://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-3986.php) you'll find exemples of these prepositions.

Comment: Apologies, I had meant to say it's "aux" for *plural* countries.

Comment: NP yes you are right, we says je suis aux Etats unis, aux bahamas etc...

Comment: *Un pieu* (no capital letter) is slang for *lit*, bed, and it has no *x* in the singular. So your sentence should be written *Je suis au pieu*.