# Différentes prépositions pour les noms des départements

Tags: prépositions, indications-de-lieu, noms-propres

Pour chaque département, nous utilisons des prépositions différentes lorsque nous construisons des phrases.
Par exemple:

1. **Dans l**'Indre mais **en** Indre-et-Loire
2. **Dans le** Cher mais **en** Charente
3. **Dans le** Calvados mais **en** Corrèze
4. **Dans l**'Eure mais **en** Eure-et-Loir
5. **Dans la** Marne mais **en** Haute-Marne
6. **Dans le** Morbihan mais **en** Corse
7. **En** Mayenne mais **Dans la** Meuse

Y a-t-il une règle ou une raison historique pour ces différences ?

Comment: Related to this: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/21/when-to-use-en-vs-dans

Comment: Plus généralement, voir [« À », « en », « à la », « au(x) » : quel déterminant utiliser pour un pays, une province, ou une ville ?](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/16974/%C3%80-en-%C3%A0-la-aux-quel-d%C3%A9terminant-utiliser-pour-un-pays-une)

Answer (score 3):

*En* indique une région historique ou un 'pays', c'est à dire une ancienne dénomination territoriale.

*Dans* indique un lieu précis, un nom localisé.

> *En Corse* (dans l'île) ...
>
> *Dans la Corse-du-sud* se trouve le cap de Bonifacio
>
> *En Charentes* (Charente et Charente-Inférieure devenue Charente-Maritime en 1941) représente une ancienne région attachée à un fleuve côtier, *dans la Charente* vous trouverez la plupart des distilleries de cognac.
>
> En Arles : dans et autour de la ville d’Arles.
>
> À Arles : à l’intérieur du territoire de la commune d'Arles, Arles intra-muros.

D'une façon générique, pour les noms précédés de *en* dans les exemples fournis :  Liste des hôtels *dans le (l' ou la)* ... signifie que l'on se référence au département administratif de l'hôtel qui aura le code postal de ce département.

Comment: J’ai toujours trouvé intéressant l’histoire & l’existence du Territoire de Belfort & cette question & votre réponse, toutes les deux intéressantes, me font demander si c’est «en Territoire de Belfort» ou «dans le Territoire de Belfort». J’ai vu les deux, mais les pluparts des «en» ont l’aire de s’agir des annonces immobilières donc j’en prend avec un grain de sel & je penche vers «dans le». Qu’en pensez-vous? Peut-être il serait plus facile pour moi à mettre tous les 105(?) (avec les DOM & les TOM) en mémoire pour pouvoir dire «dans le 90» et même «dans le…» pour l’ensemble sans réfléchir!

Comment: @PapaPoule Cette histoire se passe* en* Territoire de Belfort, il s'agit de la représentation que l'on se fait d'une zone géographique, mais vous trouverez *dans le* Territoire de Belfort le fameux Lion dont une copie se trouvait *dans* la Seine, département supprimé en 68. Ce bronze est donc maintenant *dans* Paris (département et ville) place Denfert-Rochereau, on pourrait même dire *dans le* Paris historique, tout près de l'entrée des catacombes .

Answer (score 3):

D'une façon générale, *en* se combine plutôt avec des féminins singuliers ou des masculins singuliers à voyelle initiale (en Corse (FS), en Israël (MS, VI)) et dans ce cas il alterne plutôt avec *au(x)* (au Népal (CI), aux Antilles (FP)).

Les féminins sont susceptibles d'apparaître avec les deux constructions avec des préférences variées mais pas les masculins à consonne initiale...

Answer (score 2):

Généralement, on utilise « *dans* » et l'article avec les noms de *départements français* (ex. *dans le Vaucluse*). Dans certains cas, tel celui du nom composé singulier ou du nom simple possiblement confondu avec celui de l'ancienne *province*<sup>1</sup>, « *en* » est aussi possible (ex. *en Haute-Marne, en Vaucluse*). Enfin « *en* » l'emporte avec *Savoie* et *Corse*.<sup>2</sup> On peut remarquer que l'emploi général du « *dans* » pour les départements contraste avec l'emploi historique pour les noms de villes, où on utilisait le plus souvent, jusqu'au XVII<sup>e</sup> (et parfois aujourd'hui à dessein), et malgré la concurrence avec le « *à* », le « *en* » (« *Le roi envoya Parmenion devant en Damas.* », Vaugelas, trad. de *Quinte-Curce*). Le « [*dans*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dans) » peut alors, selon le verbe, être employé pour signifier explicitement « *à l'intérieur de* » la ville. Voir aussi « [*en*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/en) » à II. A. 1) au *TLFi* et surtout *Le bon usage* (Grevisse et Goosse, *ed.* Boeck/Duculot) au §1051 a), d'où est tiré l'essentiel des éléments qui précèdent, pour d'autres cas de figure et plusieurs détails.

---

<sub>1. Pour les noms provinces feminins ou débutant par une voyelle (« *dans* » reste possible avec ce genre de cas: *dans l'Anjou*), on utilise « *en* » (ex. *en Normandie*); les noms masculins et à initiale consonantique, on peut avoir soit l'un soit l'autre, mais rarement « *au* ».</sub>

<sub>2. Pour les noms *féminins* de *grandes îles proches ou lointaines*, en contexte d'identification du lieu, on utilise « *en* »; les noms *féminins* de *petites îles lointaines*, « *à la* » (ex. ~ *Réunion*, ~ *Martinique*); les noms de *petites îles d'Europe*/les *noms masculins* de *grandes îles lointaines*, « *à* » seul.</sub>