# « SO Rétablissez la confiance en FL » ou « SO Rétablissez la confiance dans FL »

Tags: choix-de-mot

***[Attribution du bounty](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/52957674#52957674)***

---

***Avant propos***

J’ai changé le verbe de mon intitulé suite à la proposition de *[Papa Poule](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/40647/848)*, c’est un effet de sérendipité, de trouver quelque chose que l’on ne cherchait pas, mais qui éclaire vos recherches en cours.

Cela prend en compte les remarques formulées dans certaines réponses et ne change rien à l’enjeu du bounty : le choix entre *en* et *dans*.

Sentez-vous libre de compléter ou de modifier vos réponses.

---

***Question***

---

Lorsque j’ai validé le changement de l’intitulé de mon profil, je me suis aperçu que le choix de *à* n’était pas satisfaisant ; il me faut attendre que le nouvel an soit passé de quelques jours pour pouvoir le corriger.

Je penchais pour « Rendez confiance *en* FL », mais les contextes de *[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rendre%20confiance%20en%2Crendre%20confiance%20dans&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crendre%20confiance%20en%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crendre%20confiance%20dans%3B%2Cc0)* « Rendez confiance *dans* FL » semblent être plus adaptés à la situation.

Quel choix faire pour être en accord avec tous ceux qui ont apprécié ce site, pour qu’à nouveau on s’y sente à l’aise ?

---

<sup>*Complément*</sup>

Les contextes du *Ngram* utilisé ci-dessus affiche les extraits de livre, j’ai trouvé *[pour **dans** :](https://www.google.com/search?lr=lang_fr&biw=1226&bih=533&tbs=lr%3Alang_1fr&tbm=bks&ei=HL3vXY_FO62flwTEg6-wCg&q=%22rendre%20confiance%20dans%22&oq=%22rendre%20confiance%20dans%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...19441.29331.0.30933.9.7.2.0.0.0.46.296.7.7.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.0QARY_xgaAo)*

> — … ont de manière évidente pour objectif de *rendre confiance **dans*** l'action publique …
>
> — Pour *rendre confiance **dans*** l'avenir des entreprises …

et *[pour **en** :](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22rendre%20confiance%20en%22&lr=lang_fr&tbs=lr:lang_1fr&tbm=bks&ei=ML_vXeCfJ4GdlwThkLjQCA&start=10&sa=N&ved=0ahUKEwjg98_4t6vmAhWBzoUKHWEIDooQ8tMDCH0&biw=1226&bih=533&dpr=1.3)*

> — *Rendre confiance **en*** l'éducation nationale, …
>
> — … besoin de *rendre confiance **en*** l'avenir … // Comment leur *rendre confiance **en*** l'avenir ?

Même si l’usage utilise l’infinitif, le verbe en lui-même supporte l’impératif, impératif employé ici pour une supplique et non pour un ordre comminatoire. En conséquence, que choisir entre *dans* et *en*.

Pour être cohérent avec *[Gilles 'SO nous est hostile'](http://french.stackexchange.com/users/5/)* et *[Laure SO - Écoute-nous](http://french.stackexchange.com/users/358/)* j’ai rajouté ***SO -*** dans mon futur intitulé

---

<sup>***PS*** : Pour des raisons de nombre de caractères acceptés l’avant-propos a été abandonné.</sup>

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102126/discussion-on-question-by-cl-r-rendez-confiance-a-fl--se-rendez-confiance-en-f).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for answering in English:

Although your question concerns which preposition (*en* or *dans*) would go better with "**Rendez** confiance en/dans FL," I cannot resist the temptation to suggest that you also consider the following input concerning whether *rendre* is the best verb to use in your new/future SE moniker and, in the process, whether you should add a definite article before *confiance*: :

To the extent that [this ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=redonner+confiance%2Cremettre+confiance%2Cr%C3%A9tablir+la+confiance%2Crendre+confiance%2Credonner+la+confiance%2Crendre+la+confiance%2Cremettre+la+confiance&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1700&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Credonner%20confiance%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bredonner%20confiance%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BRedonner%20confiance%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cr%C3%A9tablir%20la%20confiance%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Br%C3%A9tablir%20la%20confiance%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BR%C3%A9tablir%20la%20confiance%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Crendre%20confiance%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Brendre%20confiance%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BRendre%20confiance%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Credonner%20la%20confiance%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crendre%20la%20confiance%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cremettre%20la%20confiance%3B%2Cc0) means anything at all, it could be seen as showing that of the four verbs used in my search (*redonner*, *rendre*. *remettre*, and *rétablir*), only *redonner* and *rendre* get hits when used without *confiance*'s definite article (*la*), with "*redonner confiance*" being used substantially more often than "*rendre confiance*" (*redonner* was included in the search because of the connection it has with *rendre*, as aptly shown by USER LPH in paragraph 2 of his/her answer).

Based on the ngram search results mentioned/linked to above, I would suggest that your new name contain "*redonnez confiance*" instead of "*rendez confiance*" **if** you insist on omitting the *la* between the verb and *confiance*.
  **However**, if you are open to including that *la*, I would urge you to consider that "rétablir la confiance" is shown as a not-too-distant second behind "*redonner confiance*" on the said ngram and further, to therefore consider using:

> *SO, **rétablissez** la confiance en/dans FL/FSE*.

My preference for *rétablir*  surely stems from my lack, as a non-native speaker of French, of a full understanding of all the relevant meanings of both *redonner* and *rendre*, for it is this lack of understanding that makes me feel unsure about what exactly is the message you want to send to SE.

One problem I see (again with my non-native eyes/ears) with *rétablir*, however, is that it could imply a neutral stance regarding who is responsible for the current state of affairs/the current lack of trust/confidence at/in FL. Your new/future name with *rétablir* could be seen as simply asking SE to restore/re-establish trust/confidence without the implication, which would probably be present with *redonner* or *rendre*, that they are the only ones who took away/destroyed what needs to be given back/restored.
If this "neutral" problem that I see with *rétablir* is a valid concern, I would certainly understand if you view it as a "deal breaker."

---

In an attempt to make my answer at least a little less "off-topic" (i.e., until now I have addressed only which verb to use and not which preposition, as you requested), I'll simply point to [this ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=redonner+confiance+en%2Cr%C3%A9tablir+la+confiance+en%2Cr%C3%A9tablir+la+confiance+dans%2Credonner+confiance+dans%2Credonner+confiance%2Cr%C3%A9tablir+la+confiance%2Crendre+confiance+en%2Crendre+confiance%2Crendre+confiance+dans&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1700&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Credonner%20confiance%20en%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cr%C3%A9tablir%20la%20confiance%20en%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cr%C3%A9tablir%20la%20confiance%20dans%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Credonner%20confiance%20dans%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Credonner%20confiance%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bredonner%20confiance%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BRedonner%20confiance%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cr%C3%A9tablir%20la%20confiance%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Br%C3%A9tablir%20la%20confiance%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BR%C3%A9tablir%20la%20confiance%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crendre%20confiance%20en%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Crendre%20confiance%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Brendre%20confiance%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BRendre%20confiance%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crendre%20confiance%20dans%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Credonner%20confiance%20en%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cr%C3%A9tablir%20la%20confiance%20en%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cr%C3%A9tablir%20la%20confiance%20dans%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Credonner%20confiance%20dans%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Credonner%20confiance%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bredonner%20confiance%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BRedonner%20confiance%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cr%C3%A9tablir%20la%20confiance%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Br%C3%A9tablir%20la%20confiance%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BR%C3%A9tablir%20la%20confiance%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crendre%20confiance%20en%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Crendre%20confiance%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Brendre%20confiance%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BRendre%20confiance%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crendre%20confiance%20dans%3B%2Cc0), which could suggest that *en* might be better with "*rendre confiance*" and "*redonner confiance*" whereas *dans* might be better with "*rétablir la confiance*".

With all of the above in mind, including my interpretation of the "results" of that second *ngram* and my understanding of [this arguably relevant, if not spot-on, use of **dans**](https://books.google.com/books?id=emEFL2bcCWkC&pg=PA298&dq=%22r%C3%A9tablit+la+confiance+dans%22&hl=en&ppis=_c&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi7-NC777rmAhWHrFkKHWXBC0sQ6AEwBHoECAIQAg#v=onepage&q=%22r%C3%A9tablit%20la%20confiance%20dans%22&f=false) **>>>**, I would suggest the following for your new name:

> *SO, rétablissez la confiance dans FL/FSE*

**>>>** "Cet officier rétablit la confiance dans ceux qui lui avaient été assignés" from *Histoire de l'expédition de Russie, avec un atlas et 3 vignettes*,
by Georges de Chambray via *Googlebooks*

Comment: Mes capacités en version anglaise dépassent largement celles nécessaires au thème… Bien qu’elle paraisse "off-topic", votre réponse dénoue un problème latent relevé dans certaines réponse : *rétablir* convient parfaitement à la situation, alors que *rendre* est plus "généraliste", c’est pourquoi j’ai accepté votre réponse et modifié mon l'intitulé de mon profil. En revanche *rétablir* induit de *revenir à un état antérieur* (celui de l’éthique respectée), oxymoron d’avenir (incertain).

Comment: Pour l’équité : « J’attire votre attention sur le changement de verbe dans l’intitulé, cela peut influencer votre choix [*en|dans*] »

Answer (score 1):

On peut commencer par les usages avec des tournures similaires avec d'autres verbes, avec en trame de fond la coexistence de différents emplois des prépositions (*à* et *sur* ici, dans la présentation au LBU) :

> Après *avoir **confiance*** (ou ***foi***), *mettre sa confiance*
>   (ainsi qu'après *prendre confiance*, plus rare), on a ordinairement
>   *en*, qui s'impose devant un pronom personnel ; souvent *dans*, surtout quand le nom qui suit est accompagné d'un article ; parfois
>   *à*, plutôt littéraire en général (voir cependant le deuxième ex. de PROUST (« *Il parait qu'elle a bien confiance À des médailles* [dit la
>   servante Françoise] », *Rech*.) **H2** (On a aussi employé *sur* : *Tu
>   mets ta confiance SUR quelques lettres mystérieuses* (Montesquieu)).
>
> *Rosanette n'avait confiance EN personne* (FLAUB., Educ., II, 4)
>    [...]
>
> ***Faire confiance à***, signalé par [Littré](https://www.littre.org/definition/confiance), dans son Supplément, comme appartenant à la langue juridique, a trouvé dans l'usage
>   courant, même littéraire, depuis le début du XX e siècle (peut-être à
>   la faveur de *faire crédit à*), une belle fortune, malgré la
>   résistance des puristes. L'Ac. lui a fait bon accueil depuis 1988.
>
> *Le bon usage*, Grevisse et Goosse, éd. Duculot, 14<sup>e</sup>, § 292+H2)

On lira avec intérêt le reste de l'article. La BDL tient un propos similaire dans son article sur « [avoir confiance](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?Th=2&t1=&id=4295) » (mais tire les mêmes constats pour : *avoir foi, placer sa confiance, mettre sa confiance, garder confiance, prendre confiance*) et indique même que la préposition *en* serait plus courante avec un nom de personne.

Si on assimilait la tournure avec *rendre* en question à celles-ci (ou [non](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/rdp-srch?lang=fra&srchtxt=rendre&cur=1&nmbr=6&lettr=indx_catlog_r&page=9XTI8kn0yYAA.html#zz9XTI8kn0yYAA), en l'assimilant à *rendre la liberté à qqn* ce serait ***à*** ; ou partiellement, voir : *[mettre](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/rdp-srch?lang=fra&srchtxt=confiance&cur=6&nmbr=10&lettr=indx_catlog_m&page=9XTInh50g8AA.html#zz9XTInh50g8AA), [perdre](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/rdp-srch?lang=fra&srchtxt=confiance&cur=7&nmbr=10&lettr=indx_catlog_p&page=9XTI8gj0xAAA.html#zz9XTI8gj0xAAA), [placer](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/rdp-srch?lang=fra&srchtxt=confiance&cur=8&nmbr=10&lettr=indx_catlog_p&page=9Qj0oi-EBAAA.html#zz9Qj0oi-EBAAA), [retirer](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/rdp-srch?lang=fra&srchtxt=confiance&cur=10&nmbr=10&lettr=indx_catlog_r&page=9Qj0yNnedMmA.html#zz9Qj0yNnedMmA)*), ou que son emploi y correspondait, et que l'on déterminait que le nom du site (FL ; *French Language*) s'apparente davantage à un nom de personne qu'à un nom commun alors on pourrait penser que ***en*** serait plus courant voire qu'elle « s'imposerait » etc. Loin d'être une conclusion il s'agit plutôt d'un point de départ.

Comment: La forme normalisée serait « SO, Rendez-*nous* confiance [*en|dans*] FL » si tous les lecteurs du site étaient impliqués, si c’était une revendication pour le rétablissement d’un droit. La suppression du -*nous* interpelle l'éthique de SO mise en cause par celle des modérateurs de FL. Le *à* n’est pas de mise (c’est la confiance qui se donne *à* …), car ce n’est pas à nous de participer au rétablissement de la confiance [*en|dans*] SO , mais l’inverse

Comment: @cl-rRendezconfianceàFL Je vais y réfléchir davantage. Peut-être que je comprends mal la phrase pour les raisons évoquées en commentaire.

Comment: J’attire votre attention sur le changement de verbe dans l’intitulé, cela peut influencer votre choix [*en|dans*]

Answer (score 1):

Personnellement, je choisirai la 1ère expression e.g `Rendez confiance en FL` car il ne s'agit pas de conforter seulement la plateforme FL le site internet, mais également sa communauté (sans elle, le site est voué à disparaître, ce qui pourrait être fâcheux). De plus, une grande partie de la communauté est active sur diverses autres plateformes de SE, ce qui pourrait donc être vu comme un lien pour inciter SE à travailler sur les problèmes pour TOUS les sites. Cela serait bénéfique pour tout le monde.

La principale différence dans l'usage des mots *en* et *dans* est très bien expliquée dans cette [précédente question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/21/when-to-use-en-vs-dans?rq=1) : l'usage de *dans* pourrait être erroné car il pourrait ne s'appliquer qu'à un utilisateur / groupe minoritaire d'utilisateur, or je ne pense pas que cela soit vraiment le but, *mis à part le cas de Monica, on ne peux plus vraiment parler de groupe minoritaire où nous en sommes aujourd'hui*.

---

Prenons un exemple :

> Je n'aime pas les ingrédients présents en ce sandwich.

Dans ce cas, le sujet généralise ce type de sandwich, et fait comprendre qu'il n'aimera pas son goût **quelque soit** sa forme ou sa texture.

> Je n'aime pas les ingrédients présents dans ce sandwich.

Ici cependant, le sujet indique qu'il n'aime pas ce sandwich spécifiquement, mettant en cause le travail de la personne l'ayant préparé, mais qu'il pourrait l'aimer dans d'autres circonstances (le pain a pris l'humidité, les œufs sont trop cuits, ...)

NB : Même si la coutume utilise *SO*, je conseillerai d'utiliser l'abréviation *SE*, car on parle ici de manifester contre **l'entreprise** et non contre une autre plateforme (rappel : **SO** pour *StackOverflow* et **SE** pour *StackExchange*). Je ne pense pas que ce nom a pour but de combattre *StackOverflow*, leurs membres et modérateurs menant probablement le même combat, et ayant même certains membres / modérateurs actifs ici et là-bas.

Comment: @LPH effectivement, l'erreur vient de moi

Comment: Ce n'est pas qu'une coutume. L'entreprise s'appelle bien (à nouveau) [SO depuis quatre ans](https://stackoverflow.blog/2015/09/15/were-changing-our-name-back-to-stack-overflow/). SE n'est donc plus que le nom de l'ensemble des sites.

Comment: J’attire votre attention sur le changement de verbe dans l’intitulé, cela peut influencer votre choix [*en|dans*]

Answer (score 0):

Il semblerait ne pas exister de locution telle que « rendre confiance à/dans/en qqc/qqu » ; le TLFi ne mentionne que l'expression « rendre confiance pour confiance ».

L'idée dans « rendre » est celle exprimée par « redonner », —cela a été mentionné dans les commentaires — et elle s'exprime au moyen d'une locution figée, « redonner confiance ». On voit à partir du TLFi que l'on n'a pas le choix d'un usage libre pour ce sens du verbe « redonner » (restituer) ; pour « confiance » il n'est pas question d'utiliser l'article ; pour « espoir » cependant on a le choix et finalement pour des termes moins souvent combinés avec « redonner » il n'est pas question de se passer de l'article. Ceci est rapporté fidèlement dans le TLFi.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/redonner)) Redonner confiance, (du) courage, (de l') espoir, des forces, du prestige, de la vigueur.

Le sens de « rendre » qui est applicable est le suivant.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rendre))
>   I. − Rendre qqn/qqc. à
>   A. − Rendre qqc. à qqn.(Re)donner ce qui est dû ou attendu.
>   2. [Qqc. désigne un inanimé abstr., obj. d'une perte] Redonner, faire recouvrer.
>    Rendre la santé, la vie à qqn.

On peut donc utiliser ce verbe selon des constructions standard pour n'importe quels concepts qui soient compatibles mais on est tenu d'employer des mots déterminants avec « confiance » (la, sa, leur, etc.). Néanmoins l'usage naissant que l'on peut constater d'après  l'ngram proposé (rendre confiance en, rendre confiance dans) autorise la considération d'une nouvelle expression figée « rendre confiance en » ou « rendre confiance dans », synonyme de l'idiome taditionnel « redonner confiance en/dans ». On remarquera que la préposition « en » est utilisée de façon très majoiritaire avec cette expression-ci et sans différence de sens ([réf.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=redonner+confiance+en%2C+redonner+confiance+dans&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Credonner%20confiance%20en%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Credonner%20confiance%20dans%3B%2Cc0) (dans : > 15 livres, en : > 55 livres)).

Il n'y a pas de différence dans l'usage de « dans » et celui de « en » dans le contexte de la question originelle, cela étant dit sur la base d'un examen des contextes trouvés dans les quelques ouvrages relevés par Google Books (dans : 12, en : 18), selon l'ngram proposé. Ceci est une première indication d'une prédilection pour « en » (vérifié aussi pour l'expression synonyme).

Le sens de « en » qui s'applique est assez clairement le suivant d'après le TLFi.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/en)) **II** **D** **1.**. [En construit avec un verbe trans. indir. ou un subst. dér.]
>   1. [Avec des verbes, des loc. verbales ou des subst. du type : croire, espérer, avoir confiance, avec foi; en introduit un compl.]
>   [Devant un pron. pers.] Dans une imagination qui croit et ne croit pas en elle-même (M. DE GUÉRIN, Journal, 1834, p. 209).
>   [Devant un nom propre] J'ai foi en Dieu qui m'a fait ma part (CLAUDEL, Annonce, 1948, III, 2, p. 190)
>
> - « Nous tous, ici-bas, croyons en Adolf Hitler, notre Führer... et (nous confessons) que le national-socialisme est la seule foi qui mène notre peuple au salut. »
>     CAMUS, L'Homme révolté, 1951, p. 227.

On remarque que ce même dictionnaire ne fournit pas de définition pour « dans »  qui corresponde aussi bien à ce contexte sémantique, d'où une seconde indication dans le sens de confirmer une prédilection pour « en ».
Il s'agit de rendre leur confiance **en/dans** le FSE à des personnes, donc faire en sorte que ces personnes aient confiance **en** le FSE. On remarque que pour l'expression « avoir confiance » on utilise très peu « dans » ([réf.1](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=je+n%27ai+pas+confiande+dans%2Cje+n%27ai+pas+confiance+en&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cje%20n%27ai%20pas%20confiance%20en%3B%2Cc0), [réf.2](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nous+avons+confiance+en%2Cnous+avons+condiance+dans&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnous%20avons%20confiance%20en%3B%2Cc0), [réf.3](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=il+a+confiance+en%2C+il+a+confiance+dans&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cil%20a%20confiance%20en%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cil%20a%20confiance%20dans%3B%2Cc0)). Comme il s'agit de la même relation sémantique que dans « rendre confiance », une troisième indication de l'existence d'une prédilection pour « en » (celle-ci étant plus forte) devient ainsi apparente.

Tout ceci m'amène à penser que s'il n'y a pas  de contre-indication proscrivant l'usage de « dans » il n'y a pas non plus la preuve d'un usage spécialisé et qu'en plus c'est « en » qui prédomine largement. Il me semble que « en » serait un très bon choix.

Selon mon point de vue ce n'est pas tout ce qui puisse être discuté en rapport avec la correction de ce slogan. « SO » et « FL », ce dernier sigle étant de façon plus appropriée « FSE », sont des sigles d'organisations, comme OTAN, ONU, UNICEF. Il serait tout à fait anormal de trouver même dans une manifestation un slogan tel que « ONU rend confiance en  UNICEF » ; on doit prendre en compte  deux principes avec lesquels on n'a pas encore transigé dans la langue française. Le premier est que l'on n'interpelle pas un organisme ou une organisation en proférant son nom ; le second est aussi évident à tous : l'article est toujours utilisé avec le sigle d'une organisation. Par exemple, lorsque le sigle est utilisé dans « le foyer socio-éducatif » le résultat est de façon consistante  « le FSE ».  Pourquoi introduire un nouvel usage en plus de celui qui existe déjà ? Il n'y a rien de plus derrière cette nouvelle pratique que l'influence de l'anglais et un manque total de considération pour le système du français et l'unité de cette langue. C'est un anglicisme non toléré pour l'instant et à mon avis non tolérable. Au vu de ces principes une formulation telle que la suivante serait raisonnable.

- Que le SO rende confiance en le FSE

Comment: … une touche d’humour, sur scène :  "Que le SO rende confiance en le FSE " aurait pour réplique "Toi parler bien la France". Ce qui n’enlève rien aux arguments qui précèdent :-)

Comment: @ celles, @ ceux qui votent anonymement négatif : Respecter l’éthique du site s’adresse aussi à vous, "Argumentez les votes négatifs"

Comment: @Fólkvangr Les votes positifs n'ont pas à être justifiés mais c'est exactement ce que certains font pour montrer en quoi une réponse peut avoir de la valeur ; cependant, dans le cas d'un vote négatif, qui est une indication au lecteur que quelque chose au moins est inacceptable dans une réponse, n'est-il pas constructif de lui  montrer précisément **ainsi qu**'à l'auteur de la réponse où est le problème ? Même l'auteur, qui est sensé croire en ce qu'il dit, ne sait pas ce qu'on lui reproche, en particulier dans des réponses de  50 lignes.

Comment: @Fólkvangr — L’éthique dont je parle concerne l’échange de points de vue dans le respect mutuel, base de tout échange *courtois* (Moyen-Âge), *honnête* (Renaissance), *positif* IIIème millénaire. Ce n’est pas parce que le programme est binaire, qu’il faut avoir une conscience formatée, les commentaires sont là pour y remédier, pour manifester l’intérêt porté à l’Autre et pointer une incohérence, une erreur, ou un choix sujet à discussion. Il y a un risque de dérive *ad nominem*, et il serait bon que des vérifications soient faites pour s’assurer que ce n’est pas le cas, et je suis d’accord

Comment: pour qu’ils ne soient pas validés sans commentaire argumenté … je retrouverais ainsi le site que j’ai pu apprécier pour ses qualités éthiques.

Comment: J’attire votre attention sur le changement de verbe dans l’intitulé, cela peut influencer votre choix [*en|dans*]

Comment: @cl-rRendezconfianceàFL J'ai remarqué ce changement et je pense qu'il fausse la question ; il me semblait que cela était important, peut-être selon une possible   intuition de votre part que le nouvel usage (rendre confiance) valait la peine qu'on lui donne une chance. Néanmoins le terme finalement choisi me semble préférable. « rendre la confiance » me laisse mal à l'aise. Je ne crois pas pouvoir essayer de récupérer quoi que ce soit dans ma réponses en ce qui concerne cette partie. Qu'elle reste ainsi, conçue pour la question initiale.

Comment: Je me suis longtemps accroché à "Rendez confiance", et, petit à petit je me suis rendu compte que cela ressemblait plus à un slogan avec un côté vindicatif qu’à l'ébauche d’un dialogue apaisé, hérité de l'éthique que je souhaite retrouver.